# In Django, how can I perform the following many-to-many query (using a through table)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In my model I have a table for users (who are students or instructors - I have a UserProfile table that is connected to auth.User), a table for courses, and a table called enrollment, which records which students are enrolled in which courses.  My models.py is as follows:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="Instructor")
    students   = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through='Enrollment')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user       = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    role       = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=ROLE_CHOICES) # 'stud' or 'inst'

class Enrollment(models.Model):
    course   = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    student  = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

For a given User, I would like to find all the courses s/he is enrolled in.  How can I do this?

Also, where can I find a thorough explanation of how to do queries in Django, preferably with lots of examples that slowly increase in complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If instead of a `User` instance you have the `username` field from the `User` instance you could do the following:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(students__user__username='thespecificusername')
```

The scenario you're constructing is very similar to the one discussed here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I tried this, but got the following error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'user_username' into field. Choices are: Instructor, course, enrollment, notes, role, studentanswer, user` Some of those options are specific to the details in my model that I left out of the question above, I'm afraid.

Comment: Looks like @Alasdair fixed my missing underscore between user and username. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Clearly I need to do some deep grokking of the docs on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `UserProfile` instance `user_profile`, then try:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(students=user_profile)
```

if you have a `User` instance `user`, then you can use double underscore notation.

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(students__user=user)
```

For an explanation, I would start with the django docs for [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). Other people might have some other suggestions.

As an aside: in this case, unless you are using a legacy db, you don't really need to explicitly define the joining table `Enrollment`, as you haven't defined any extra fields.

Comment: Thanks very much.  If I do not explicitly define the enrollments table, then will I not be able to use the admin area to enroll students in courses?

Comment: If you do not explicity define the enrollments table, you would be able to add students to a course in the `CourseAdmin`. The default widget isn't very convenient, so you could set [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) or [`filter_vertical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical). You could also check out [many to many inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).